# How to block all traffic on Win10 except for 2 programs

Tags: router, firewall, nas, windows-firewall

I have win10 Pro on a offline computer.  I have a Synology NAS.  So, I have the internet cable plugged in and have everything except for port 5000 (the NAS) disabled.  Therefor no internet, no programs online, no services etc.  Now I have another program that need to access the internet.  Is there a easy way to just allow that one program and the NAS?  Like with a firewall or something?  Everything I see is ALL programs and everything.  Or you have to do all of them individually.  Which is 1000s or so.

Comment: By default Windows policy for outgoing connections it to allow connections, but you can revert it in firewall to disallow and manually allow only particular  programs.

Comment: @Akina What would be a 3rd party solution?  If there is one.

Comment: @Akina Are you sure that **deny all except this** isn't possible? It easily can be set in firewall properties

Comment: @Alex how would you set this up?  I set block ALL like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9qms8gQ-SI Then added a rule to one program (test in this case for chrome) and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

By default Windows's firewall allows outgoing connections, but you can override this to mode when every outgoing connection will be blocked by default unless you explicitly allow it.

Go to:

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall
```

then switch to `Advanced settings` and do these 3 steps shown on screenshots.

On the second screenshot you should change outgoing rule for all profiles:

```
Domain, Private and Public
```

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

Comment: @Alex  Thank you.  That is just the same as creating a Block All rule and disabling and enabling it right?  I would have to do that every time I wanted to use the program.  That is one solution.  But I am hoping there is a better one out there.

Comment: @BrianTochilin No, creating `Block All rule` as on YouTube video isn't the same. You can add in outgoing rules  **allow** permissions only for specific program(s) and this changes will be persistent. You can actually create a couple of `netsh` scripts that would allow/disallow your programs on demand.